# Regarding the unilateral Laplace transform of LTI systems

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

Consider an LTI system described by the following differential equation,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_k\frac{d}{dt^k}y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{M}b_k\frac{d}{dt^k}x(t)
$$

With initial conditions,

$$
y(t)|_{t=0}, \left.\frac{d}{dt}y(t)\right|_{t=0}, \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t)\right|_{t=0}, \cdots \left.\frac{d^{N-1}}{dt^{N-1}}y(t)\right|_{t=0}
$$

In the Signals and Systems book by Simon Haykin, the following is the result of taking the unilateral Laplace transform of the above equation,

$$
A(s)Y(s) - C(s) = B(s)X(s)
$$

Where, $C(s)$ results from the initial conditions of the system.

However, shouldn't the actual unilateral Laplace be the following?

$$
A(s)Y(s) - C(s) = B(s)X(s) - D(s)
$$

Where, $D(s)$ is the contribution from the following terms,

$$
x(t)|_{t=0}, \left.\frac{d}{dt}x(t)\right|_{t=0}, \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)\right|_{t=0}, \cdots \left.\frac{d^{M-1}}{dt^{M-1}}x(t)\right|_{t=0}
$$

There was nothing mentioned in the text about $x(t)$ and its behaviour at time $t=0$.

Comment: $C(s)$ I bet are the IC of $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ combined or they are assuming zero IC for $x$ which wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @dustin In the book the definition is $C(s) = \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_ks^{k-1}\left.\frac{d^l}{dt^l}y(t)\right|_{t=0}$. So, they have basically ignored the value of $x(t)$ and its derivatives at $t=0$.

Comment: Then they are probably assuming zero IC on $x$ which wouldn't be shocking. Not ignored. It is common practice to assume zero IC.

Comment: @dustin Yes, that is what I think as well. But it was surprising to see that they had not mentioned anything about it.

Comment: It is probably just expected.